# No instance for (Fractional [Double]) arising from the literal ‘1.0’

Tags: haskell

For class, we have to write some code for a given set of problems. One of these problems is to create an identity matrix in the form of a [[Double]] So far, I have come up with the following code. However, when I try to compile I get the following error, not sure of what I did wrong or what it means

CODE:

```
ident :: Int -> [[Double]]
ident x = identHelper x 0

identHelper :: Int -> Int -> [[Double]]
identHelper y z
  | z == 0 = ([1.0] ++ replicate (y-1) 0.0) : identHelper y 1
  | y == z = replicate (y-1) 0.0 : 1.0
  | otherwise = (replicate z 0.0 ++ [1.0] ++ replicate (y-z-1) 0.0) : identHelper y (z+1)
```

ERROR:

```
    • No instance for (Fractional [[Double]])
        arising from the literal ‘1.0’
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘1.0’
      In the expression: replicate (y - 1) 0.0 : 1.0
      In an equation for ‘identHelper’:
          identHelper y z
            | z == 0 = ([1.0] ++ replicate (y - 1) 0.0) : identHelper y 1
            | y == z = replicate (y - 1) 0.0 : 1.0
            | otherwise
            = (replicate z 0.0 ++ [1.0] ++ replicate (y - z - 1) 0.0)
                : identHelper y (z + 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is

```
           replicate (y-1) 0.0 : 1.0
```

BTW you can (and should) always leave away trailing zeroes, so

```
           replicate (y-1) 0 : 1
```

For example, say `y=4`. Then this reads

```
           [0,0,0] : 1
```

So you're trying to prepend the list `[0,0,0]` before the... *list?* `1`. How is `1` supposed to be a list?

I'm not sure what you want there, but one plausible option is `[[1]]`.